# How to add Enter function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I created a program that if you put a text in it will be saved in a text file in Visual Basic 2010 Express but I got stuck on something.

How to put if I press on <kbd>ENTER</kbd> that it will be saved too?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim a As StreamReader
Dim b As String
Dim c As String = "C:\temp\notedb.txt"

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not File.Exists(c) Then
        Dim d As FileStream
        d = File.Create(c)
        d.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Enter a note to be saved!")
    Else
        File.AppendAllText(c, TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        MsgBox("Note Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saved")
        ReadFile()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Try
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        a = File.OpenText(c)
        While a.Peek <> -1
            b = a.ReadLine()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(b)
        End While
        a.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Pressing Enter when the focus is in the Text Box...
TextBox1 in your case!

First of all you need to create a Key Press Event against that Text box:
1) Go back to the form Editor.
2) Click on the TextBox1.
3) Over on the properties grid click the Lightning Icon this will show Events label if you highlight over it.
4) Now double Click in either Key Down, Key Up or Key Press event.
5) This will have taken you to the code editor again and you should be inside one of the above events for your TextBox1.
Now you must identify what key is the user pressing!
A) 
`If e.KeyChar = Keys.Enter Then
'Place your code here to save.
 End If`

Also just some advise on this you will find that doing some reasearch ahead of asking a question will be in your favour! For example a quick search on a well known search engine engine ending in "ogle" with a simple question such as "VB.Net Detect Enter Key" will answer your question!

Hope the above helps please mark this as the answer if it resolves your question to aid others in finding the solution quickly!

Luke

Comment: Thank you for your answer Luke! i googled this but didn't find any good solutions... That's why i asked here :)